# How to write the dictionary key in a batch of text using python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I would be grateful for any help. I have a dictionary which looks like this:

TEST_versions = {'D14 2015' : 'X1', 'D12   2014' : 'X2'}

I want the key from the dictionary to be placed in my text (which I am appending to a file) so I have written:

```
for v in TEST_versions.keys():
    #print(v)
    add_code = open('make_all_ascii_files.txt','a')
    add_code.write("""
SELECT IF (Version_selector = v).""")
```

v is not taking the value of the key, rather the letter v is being appended to the file. How can I write the code so v takes the value 'D14 2015' for example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) the string with the variable:

```
for v in TEST_versions.keys():
    #print(v)
    add_code = open('make_all_ascii_files.txt','a')
    add_code.write("""
SELECT IF (Version_selector = {}).""".format(v))
```

If you have more than one variable you're formatting you can index them:

```
for v in TEST_versions:
    #print(v)
    add_code = open('make_all_ascii_files.txt','a')
    add_code.write("""
SELECT IF (Version_selector = {0}; value={1}).""".format(v, TEST_versions[v]))
```

Note that the call to `.keys()` is unnecessary in your example because python iterates over a dictionary's keys by default.

Answer (score 0):

*v* is not replaced within string itself.
You can do something like following, for example (using named placeholders)

```
for k in TEST_versions.keys():
    add_code = open('make_all_ascii_files.txt','a')
    add_code.write(
        "SELECT IF (Version_selector = %(value)s)."
        % { 'value': TEST_versions[k] }
    )
```

or

```
for k in TEST_versions.keys():
    add_code = open('make_all_ascii_files.txt','a')
    add_code.write("""SELECT IF (Version_selector = %s).""" % TEST_versions[k] )
```

or

```
for k, v in TEST_versions.items():
    add_code = open('make_all_ascii_files.txt','a')
    add_code.write("SELECT IF (Version_selector = %s)." % v)
```

or some other options for string formatting. Python got lots of options for this

I guess you'd like to review https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax for details.